# A question about Pontryagin product on $CP^{\infty}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

The homology of $\mathbb{C}P^{\infty}$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ for $i=0,2,4,...$ and zero otherwise. Pontryagin product is $H_i(\mathbb{C}P^{\infty}) \times H_j(\mathbb{C}P^{\infty})\longrightarrow H_{i+j}(\mathbb{C}P^{\infty})$. We denote the generator in $H_{2k}(\mathbb{C}P^{\infty})$ as $a_{2k}$.

Then why does $a_2^k = k! a_{2k}$?

The description here [Pontryagin Product](http://at.yorku.ca/b/ask-an-algebraic-topologist/2020/2589.htm) does not give proof of this. Please give elementary proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description I know of the $H$ space structure on $\mathbb{CP}^\infty$ is as the projectivisation of the countable vector space $\mathbb{C}[x]$, with multiplication given by multiplication of polynomials. (To check this is homotopic to your description, it suffices to check what the pullback on $H^2$ is.)

From this perspective, we have a natural basis of $2k$th homology as the fundamental class associated to the sub-projective space of polynomials of degree $\leq k$.

Now we can see what our multiplication does, taking the $k$th power of $a_2$ is the homology push forward of the top class of $(\mathbb{CP}^1)^k$ under the multiplication map. But this map factors through the projective subspace of degree $\leq k$ polynomials, and this top degree push forward from this subspace (by definition) gives our basis element $a_{2k}$.

Thus we are reduced to computing the degree (multiplication on top homology) of the map between these two smooth compact oriented manifolds: $$(\mathbb{CP}^1)^k\rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^k$$

In this nice setup (oriented smooth map of smooth manifolds) it is a classical result that the degree is equal to the cardinality of the generic preimage of the morphism. In our case, we have the open dense subset of degree $k$ polynomials with distinct roots, and for these we see that there are $k!$ preimages, given by choosing an ordering of the roots. Thus this coefficient is $k!$, and we are done.

Comment: Could you give details about why and how the map on homology factors through projective space of degree k polynomials and why we have open dense subset of degree k polynomials with distinct roots?

Comment: So for the first question, one just needs to unravel the definitions, and use that a product of $k$ polynomials of degree at most $1$ has degree at most $k$. For the second question, you can first show that the polynomials in this projective space of degree exactly $k$ are dense, then show that among polynomials of degree exactly $k$, having $k$ distinct roots is a zariski open condition, using the discriminant of a polynomial. Thus by transitivity of dense-ness, this subset is dense.

Comment: This might be naive question, but why cardinality of generic preimage is (k!)

Comment: Take a polynomial, and an ordering of its roots $\alpha_1,…\alpha_k$. Then $(x-\alpha_1,x-\alpha_2,…,x-\alpha_k)$ is a preimage. But our choice of ordering of roots was arbitrary, and since all of our roots are distinct, we have that any permutation of them is another preimage, giving $k!$ preimages. Then it’s not to tricky to show this gives all of the preimages, as a corollary of unique factorisation of a polynomial into roots.